# Unable to serially execute ```execFile()``` with ```ffmpeg-static-electron``` binary Electron

Tags: node.js, child-process, execfile, electron-react-boilerplate

I'm trying to split a number of `.mp4` videos into `.jpg` images.

The set up is using `electron-react-app`. I have used a `preload` script to enable access to limited functions with the React components.

**Problem**: Unable to serially execute the call to `execFile()` on an array of video file names. The first video file is being successfully converted but can't get the remaining videos to convert despite using `promises`.

Function in **pre-load** script (accessed in React component):

```
const ffmpeg = require("ffmpeg-static-electron")
const { execFile } = require("child_process");
...
{split: (tempReviewFolderPath, filename) => {
    execFile(`${ffmpeg.path}`, [
      "-i",
      `${path.join(tempReviewFolderPath, filename)}`,
      "-vf",
      "fps=3",
      `${path.join(tempReviewFolderPath, "image-%d.jpg")}`,
    ]),
      (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        } else {
          console.log(stdout, stderr);
        }
      };
  }
}
```

**`React` component:**

`tempReviewFolderPath` is the `filepath` to the folder contaning the videos.

`filenamesArray` is an array containing video filename strings.

`"main_process:video_to_split"` is the channel used in `electron ipc` which takes (channel, callback) as args.

```
useEffect(() => {
("main_process:video_to_split", 

 ({ tempReviewFolderPath, filenamesArray }) => {
        try {
          Promise.all(
            filenamesArray.map((filename) => {
              return new Promise((resolve) => {
                preLoad.split(tempReviewFolderPath, filename);
                resolve(filename);
              });
            })
          ).catch(console.error);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      })

}, []}
```

This only splits the first video.

I've also tried:-

**pre-load** script

```
const execFile = require("util").promisify(require("child_process").execFile);

{split: async (tempReviewFolderPath, filename) => {
    await execFile(`${ffmpeg.path}`, [
      "-i",
      `${path.join(tempReviewFolderPath, filename)}`,
      "-vf",
      "fps=3",
      `${path.join(tempReviewFolderPath, "image-%d.jpg")}`,
    ]),
      (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        } else {
          console.log(stdout, stderr);
        }
      };
  }
}
```

**`React` component:**

```
useEffect(() => {
("main_process:video_to_split", 

 ( tempReviewFolderPath, filenamesArray }) => {
        try {
              preLoad.split(tempReviewFolderPath, filename);
             } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      })

}, []}
```

Lastly (out of desperation) :

```
useEffect(() => {
  ("main_process:video_to_split", 

({ tempReviewFolderPath, filenamesArray }) => {
        let filename1 = filenamesArray[0];
        let filename2 = filenamesArray[1];

        try {
          preLoad.split(tempReviewFolderPath, filename1);
          preLoad.split(tempReviewFolderPath, filename2);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      }

)
```

Again, same problem - only the first video is split.

What am I doing wrong ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found solution:

Problem related to "image-%d.jpg" which was simply being overwritten on each iteration by map.

Solution: just added index and changed function.

```
filenamesArray.map((filename, index) => {
          return new Promise((res, rej) => {
            api_link.split(tempReviewFolderPath, filename, index);
            res(filename);
          });
        });
```